# How do I access the admissions data in college scorecard?

Tags: api, url

I am trying to access the admissions data, but I am having trouble. I keep getting this error:

```
{"errors":[{"error":"field_not_found","input":"admissions.admission_rate.overall","message":"The input field 'admissions.admission_rate.overall' (in the fields parameter) is not a field in this dataset."}]}
```

when I run this url: https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?fields=admissions.admission_rate.overall,school.name&api_key=redacted
I followed the right format to get the names from all the schools, I am just confused on how to do that here
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might have already found the answer but for anyone (like me) still searching:
**for anything other than the root fields (ID and location), you need to specify a year**. So to get admissions data, you can get the latest by including latest.admissions in your search query.

https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11525/trying-to-get-college-sat-scores-from-http-api-data-gov-ed-collegescorecard